# ORACLE Select list inconsistant with group by

Tags: oracle

I can't create my view and I don't know how to fix it. 
when trying to create the view it tries to add all the columns from select to the group by, which isn't what I want. and doesn't work anyways

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW CustomerSaleHistoryView AS
    Select  SALE.SaleID, 
        SALE.SaleDate, 
        CUSTOMER.LastName, 
        CUSTOMER.FirstName, 
        SALE_ITEM.SaleItemID, 
        SALE_ITEM.ItemID,  
        ITEM.ItemPrice,
        SUM(SALE_ITEM.ITEMPRICE),
        AVG(SALE_ITEM.ITEMPRICE)
    from    customer
    join    sale  on customer.CUSTOMERID = Sale.CUSTOMERID
    join    sale_item on sale_item.saleid = sale.saleID
    join    item      on sale_item.itemID = item.itemID 
    group by CUSTOMER.LastName, CUSTOMER.FirstName, SALE.SaleID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you query to work you MUST group by any columns that are not being aggregated with a formula like `SUM()` or `AVG()`. In your case `GROUP BY SALE.SaleID, SALE.SaleDate, CUSTOMER.LastName, CUSTOMER.FirstName, SALE_ITEM.SaleItemID, SALE_ITEM.ItemID, ITEM.ItemPrice`

What are you trying to accomplish that you don't believe this `GROUP BY` is appropriate?

Comment: even if they are part of the group by it fails

Comment: What error does it give you after fixing the GROUP BY? I'm guessing because you don't give you SUM() or AVG() fields an explicit column name such as `SUM(SALE_ITEM.ITEMPRICE) as sumOfItemPrice` it may balk.

Comment: adding the alias helped, I can't understand why the error outputs are so meaningless

Comment: @marqbrasseur - Oracle is well known for less-than-helpful error messages. After a while you get used to it...

Answer (score 0):

When using group by clause the list of columns that you are selecting should be either part of the group by clause or they should be part of an aggregate function.  In your case SALE.SaleDate, SALE_ITEM.SaleItemID, SALE_ITEM.ItemID and ITEM.ItemPrice doesn't satisfy that rule.  You need to include these to your group by clause.  Once you fix the select statement and when it returns the desired output convert that into a view.

Comment: even if they are part of the group by it fails.